# In Python, how to find out which module imports a specific module

Tags: python

For example, I have a module called "Abc". Inside Abc, I need to find out which other module imports 'Abc'. If another module called "Egf" import "Abc", is it possible to print out "Egf" inside of 'Abc'? If so how?

I know a lib called https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps/blob/master/pydeps/depgraph.py. It can build a graph by reading pyc file, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: ... out of curiosity, _why_? I don't think the interpreter gives you that information (you have `__name__`, but that's what you're imported as, not who imported you)

Comment: 1. I cannot tell you why this could be useful, but it was fun working on an answer; 2. You can get the absolute path of the file with the actual `import Abc` from `inspect.stack()`. Not exactly the name of the importing module, though. But maybe this information is also hidden somewhere (or you try importing the file, then its parent directory and so on until it fails to get the actual module...)

Comment: @Nicolas if my answer helped, please accept it. If not, please tell me why not.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This might not be a good idea and I don't know much about the internals, so I cannot guarantee that it does not break anything or works in all cases.

1. Imports happen only once, so if the modules `Def` and `Ghi` both include `import Abc`, the code in `Abc` will be executed just once.

   - Thus we need to globally modify how imports are performed.
   - `import Abc` evaluated to `builtins.__import__("Abc", ...)`, so we can override that function to check if the module to import is `Abc` and act accordingly.
2. We can see the import statements in `inspect.stack()`, but are only provided with the filename of the import statement, not the module. So if `Def.py` calls `import Abc`, we get the absolute path to `Def.py`, but do not know if it really is the submodule `Jkl.Def`.

   - My answer ignores that case and just reports `Def` in that case.
   - You could try this approach to get the actual module if `Def` is just a submodule.

     1. Assuming the absolute path to be `/home/testuser/modules/module1/Def.py` and the actual module is `module1.Def`
     2. Try `__import__("Def")`. If it works, `Def` is likely to be the importing module (or there exists another module `Def` in the search path...)
     3. In our case that should fail, so we now call `__import__("module1.Def")`. This should succeed, so we can assume that the importing module was `module1.Def`.

#### Abc.py

```
import builtins
from builtins import __import__ as builtin_import
import inspect
import os


def my_import(*args):
    """This function is intended to globally override builtins.__import__"""

    module_to_import = args[0]
    if module_to_import == "Abc":
        # for indirect imports we need to find the actual import statement in the stack
        for stackframe in inspect.stack():
            if stackframe.code_context is None:
                continue
            code = stackframe.code_context[0]
            if code.startswith(("import Abc", "from Abc")):
                # name of importing file
                importing_file = stackframe.filename  # absolute path
                importing_module = os.path.basename(importing_file).split(".")[0]
                print("Imported Abc from module", importing_module)
                break
        else:
            # This should not happen...
            print("Abc was imported but I didn't find the import statement in the stack")

    # perform the actual import
    builtin_import(*args)


# globally replace __import__
builtins.__import__ = my_import

# the first import does not use the patched __import__, so we need to do it manually
__import__("Abc")

print("I am Abc")
```

#### Def.py

```
import Abc
print("I am Def")
```

#### Ghi.py

```
import Abc
print("I am Ghi")
```

#### main.py

```
import Abc
import Def
import Ghi
```

#### Result

```
$ python3 main.py
Imported Abc from module main
I am Abc
Imported Abc from module Def
I am Def
Imported Abc from module Ghi
I am Ghi
```